# how to prevent resizing div when resizing my web browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help me to this code, how do i prevent the div resizing when i resizing the webpage.

any advice for this code sir/mam?

thanks in advance for the help.
sorry for my bad english :D

```js
/** to prevent inputing numbers in textbox enter your mobile number */
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}/** to prevent inputing numbers in textbox enter your mobile number END */
/** For Checkbox */
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery("#accept").click(function(){
if(jQuery("#button").is(":enabled"))
{
jQuery("#button").prop("disabled",true);
}
else
{
jQuery("#button").prop("disabled",false);
}
});});/** For Checkbox End*/
```

```css
.plogo{
z-index:5;
position:absolute;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
line-height: 1em;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
font-size: 72px;
text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(56,56,56),1px 1px 0 rgb(56,56,56),2px 2px 0 rgb(56,56,56),3px 3px 0 rgb(56,56,56),4px 4px 0 rgb(56,56,56),5px 5px 0 rgb(56,56,56),6px 6px 0 rgb(56,56,56), 7px 7px 0 rgb(56,56,56),8px 8px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

a {text-decoration: none;}
nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background: rgb(2,189,138);
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
}



ul li {
 font: 13px Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;
 -moz-transition: padding .05s linear;
 -ms-transition: padding .05s linear;
 -o-transition: padding .05s linear;
 transition: padding .05s linear;
  font-weight:bold;
}
ul li.drop {
 position: relative;
}
ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
 color: #eee;
 -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
ul li a:hover {
 color: #eee;
}

.dropOut .triangle {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid white;
 top: -8px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -8px;
}
.dropdownContain {
 width: 160px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -80px; /* half of width */
 top: -400px;
}
.dropOut {
 width: 160px;
 background: white;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
 transition: all .1s ease-out;
}

.dropOut ul {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.dropOut ul li {
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
 width: 125px;
 padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
 margin: 0px 10px;
 color: #777;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;
 -o-transition: background .1s ease-out;
 transition: background .1s ease-out;
}

.dropOut ul li:hover {
 background: #f6f6f6;
}

ul li:hover a { color: white; }
ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 8px; }

.wrapper {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% auto;
  margin-top: -250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  height: 100% auto;

}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
          transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
  font-weight: 200;
}


.bg-bubbles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bg-bubbles li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  bottom: -160px;
  -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
  animation: square 25s infinite;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 10%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 17s;
          animation-duration: 17s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 22s;
          animation-duration: 22s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 70%;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 80%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
          animation-delay: 3s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 32%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7s;
          animation-delay: 7s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 55%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
          animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
          animation-duration: 40s;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.bg-bubbles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 90%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
          animation-delay: 11s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}

.cacc{
 z-index: 2;
 position:relative;
 height:10px;
 width:280px;
}
input[type='text']{
 font-size:18px;
 font-family:modern, tahoma;
}
/*---------- For username --------------------------------*/
input[type='text'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
/*---------- For username End--------------------------------*/
input[type='password'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
  color: #53e3a6;}
  
  input[type='email'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
  color: #53e3a6;
  }
 .dlist{font-size: 18px; font-family:modern; color:grey; border-radius:5px; z-index:2; position:relative; }
 .cbox{ position:relative; z-index:2;}
 .logbutton {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #53e3a6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
.logbutton:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
```

```html
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:#e8e8e8; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<font class="plogo"> &nbspP . A . R . S</font>

<nav>   
  <ul>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <li><a href="plog.php">Log In</a></li>  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   <li><a href="cacc.php">Create Account</a></li> 
   <li class="drop">
    <a href="#" style=" line-height: 80px; padding: 0 20px; height: 80px;">Advertisement</a> 
    <div class="dropdownContain">
     <div class="dropOut">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#" style="color:#777;">Job Hiring</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" style="color:#777;">Tourist Spot</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" style="color:#777;">Restaurant & Bar</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" style="color:#777;">Foods</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" style="color:#777;">Party Events</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


    <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container">
  <center><h1 style="font-weight:bold;color:#fff;">CREATE ACCOUNT</h1>
  <?php
  
  ?>
  <form action=""><font style="color:#fff; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">
   Choose your Username
   <input type="text" class="cacc" placeholder="Create Username" />
   Choose your Password
   <input type="text" class="cacc" placeholder="Create Password" />
   Your Email
   <input type="email" class="cacc" placeholder="Enter your email" />
   Your First Name
   <input type="text" class="cacc" placeholder="First name" />
   Your Last Name
   <input type="text" class="cacc" placeholder="Last name" />
   Your Mobie Number
   <input type="text" onkeypress="validate(event)" class="cacc" placeholder="11 Digits Mobile Number" maxlength="11" />
   Your Birthday<br />
   <select class="dlist">
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>123</option>
   </select>
   <select class="dlist">
    <option>Day</option>
   </select>
   <select class="dlist">
    <option>Year</option>
   </select><br />
   Your Gender<br />
   <select class="dlist">
    <option>Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
   </select><br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" id="accept" required />
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Create Account" class="logbutton" disabled="disabled" id="button" />

  </font></form>
 </center></div>
 

</body>
```

please help me to this code, how do i prevent the div resizing when i resizing the webpage.

any advice for this code sir/mam?

thanks in advance for the help.
sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `min-width` CSS property to the element you want to not be resized to lower than prefered width:

```
.YOUR_DIV_CLASS {
    min-width: 500px; // Or any other width you prefer.
}
```

Or use `width` property and define width in `px` to make the div have static width.

Answer (score 0):

changing each or some of those elements (depending on your needs)

```
... {
...
width: 100%;
...
}
```

into something like:

```
... {
...
width: 980px; (or whatever numeber you need)
...
}
```